# Can non iPhone iOS devices (iPad specifically) be used to dial short USSD codes for carrier information?

Tags: ios, ipad, cellular-carriers

My data carrier provides USSD code to check the voice & data balance in the sim & iPad3 doesn't seem to have a way to dial them.

So how can I send USSD codes without jailbreaking my iPad? Is it possible at all?

USSD codes are like this: `*123*1#` for data balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not possible! The USSD code would be sent over a voice call of sorts, but there's no phone app on the iPad. The cellular access is strictly for data (at least without jailbreaking).

You'll just have to find a different way of checking your data balance! You could just keep track manually by going to Settings -> General -> Usage -> Cellular Usage. That will allow you to reset your usage statistics and then keep tabs on how much data you've used up to that point.

Comment: Too bad, I am already keeping tab on my usage, its just needed to know the pack balance & expiration date, as on my carrier when data pack gets exhausted, it starts deducting money out of voice balance & that's expensive.

Comment: @Ashfame Many carriers allow web access to the same data and some even have apps in the App Store to make this sort of query easier on you.

Comment: @bmike Yep! I got to know my carrier `Airtel, India` also has an app to check voice/data balance. Thanks!